# What is the best way to allocate hardware resources

Tags: algorithm

Let me describe the problem.

I want to create an engine that would allocate hardware from hardware inventory.
For example.
I would provide hardware information input and the engine will match the exact hardware and return me the allocated hardware. if it does not find the exact match it should give me a higher version or lower version based on availability.

below is the abstract hardware info

```html
{
 "item_type": "Desktop",
 "s_description": "x86 Desktop PC (w/ Monitor, Keyboard, Mouse)",
 "facility_id": "100",
 "quantity_requested": "40",
 "capabilities": [
  {
   "item_type": "MEMORY",
   "s_description": "MB Memory",
   "item_num": "123",
   "facility_cd": "PSC",
   "quantity_funded": "0"
  },
  {
   "item_type": "INTERNAL_DISK",
   "s_description": "GB Internal Disk",
   "itemId": "456",
   "r_item_id": "11226",
   "facility_cd": "PSC"
  },
  {
   "item_type": "CPU",
   "s_description": "Intel Core i5 3.1 GHz (Quad-Core) CPU",
   "itemId": "789",
   "facility_id": "100"
  },
  {
   "item_type": "MONITOR",
   "s_description": "Flat Panel Monitor",
   "itemId": "1011",
   "facility_id": "100"
  }
 ]
}
```

Inventory would have millions of resources of different types. 
What is the best approach to search and find a suitable resource?
There must be many algorithms defined, but googling did not help me. 
I have no idea where to start. Any resources, suggestion, idea is welcome?

Comment: Sounds like you want a database.

Comment: Will it not be slow ?

Comment: you will have to try it. There are many databases for many different purposes. But the one thing that databases are meant to do very well (if you use your indices correctly) is retrieve data fast. It then all depends on how you model your data and how you access it

Comment: What if I load my inventory in memory and apply some search?

Comment: `Inventory would have millions of resources of different types.` - give it a try. If you have enough resources (I mean RAM) to always hold all of your data in memory, then it will certainly be quicker. I imagine though you will have a hard time scaling that solution